# DataTables 1.10.5 Ajax - how to add parameters to TR or TDs?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I would like to load datatable data with AJAX and add some parameters to the rows and cells (classes or 'data' attributes). The most tricky part is that I have a PHP helper that creates javascript. For example:

```
$datatables = array(
            'type' => array(
                'bAutoWidth' => false,
                'ajax' => site_url('admin/parameters/area_add_type_table_data_ajax/' . $t_id),
                'paging' => false,
                'searching' => true,
                'columns' => array(
                    array('width' => '20%', 'class' => 'text-center')
                ),
                'info' => true,
                'scrollX' => true,
            ),
        );
```

This PHP array is JSON-encoded and creates the javascript that displays the table.

The ajax source also exits JSON-encoded array, for example:

```
$data = array('data' => array(array('SOME TEXT HERE...'), array('SOME TEXT IN ANOTHER ROW...')); exit(json_encode($data);
```

One row, produced by this code is:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td class="text-center">SOME TEXT HERE...</td></tr>
```

But then I need to add some "parameters" to final rows (tr) and some cells (tds) (attributes in double asterisks).

```
<tr role="row" class="odd" **data-id="##"**><td class="text-center" **data-content="unit_short" data-id="##"**>SOME TEXT HERE...</td></tr>
```

That IDs are depending on the current data in the row, so they are variable.

(I apologise for the one row code examples)

Thank you for any help. If it is not possible to do it in my "PHP-way", write at least a solution in pure JS.

Comment: I don't see any Javascript code. Maybe you mean the _$datatables_ array and the _'columns'_ - _'class'_ item? Where comes the _'data'_ attribute from?

Comment: @DelightedD0D As the title says, v 1.10.5 :)

Comment: @hherger I simply need to add not only the content of the cells (included in array $data) but only add some additional parameters to the created <tr> and <td>. I know that classes can be added to <td>s by defining 'columns' - 'class'. But I need also add attribute 'data-id' with a value of particular ID which is different for every row. Also need to add 'data-id' attribute to <tr> itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how your PHP helper works, but you can use the [**`createdRow`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) callback to do that :

```
createdRow: function(tr, data, index) {
   $(tr).attr('data-id', '##');
   $('td', tr).eq(1)
              .attr('data-content', 'unit_short')
              .attr('data-id', '##')
}
```

It is not clear from the question what `##` is and where it come from,  but this is at least the way to go. You can use `index` if there is no `##` available.

Comment: I have considered using this function. Maybe is the only way to do that. But unfortunately not by my PHP helper, because this will be written as key=value in an array. But if I use json_encode for the array, let's say array('createdRow' => 'function(...)'), the value with the function you wrote will be encoded as a string, not as a function itself. This will need to change that helper or get rid of it at all and use pure javascript approach.

Comment: @Peter - how is the script / javascript object literal rendered on the page? If it is rendered as `var datatablesObject = { ...}` then you can "manually" add the function to the object literal by `datatablesObject.createdRow = function(tr, data, index) { ...} ` ...

Comment: That's a very good idea. I thought I can rid of this PHP helper but it generates very usefull "default" settings for all datatables. For example: `$('#dataTable_categories').DataTable({"paging":true,"searching":true,"info":true,"aaSorting":[],"language":{"url":"dataTables.Slovak.json"},"columnDefs":[],"bAutoWidth":false,"iDisplayLength":10,"bLengthChange":true,"columns":[...],"scrollX":true});});` So you think that I could link that `$('#dataTable_categories).DataTable(...)` to a variable and then add the createdRow function to it?